# How to repeat list number in the case of identical string in array

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function that iterates through an array and will assign a list number to each individual string. In the case of there being two identical strings next to each other, I want this list number to repeat. For instance, if b occurs twice on both the 2nd and 3rd iteration, both should have list number '2'. How do I achieve this?

```
const arr = ["a", "b", "b", "c", "d"]

function list(){
    let count = 1
    arr.forEach((x) => {
        console.log(count + '.' + x)
        count++
    })
}

list()
```

should log

```
1.a
2.b
2.b
3.c
4.d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a `count` start with 1.

check if the `current index value` and `next index value` are not same increment the count by 1 else keep it as it is.

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "b", "c", "d"]
let count =1;

arr.forEach((e,index)=>{
  console.log(count , ' . ', arr[index] )
  if(e !== arr[index+1]){
    count++;
  }
})
```